# How to Pass a Dependency to a Castle Windsor Typed Factory

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, factory

I'm using Castle Windsor 3.3 and have a ViewModel that needs an `IMachine` instance injected.  This data is not available until runtime, so I'm trying to use a Typed Factory.

```
public MachDataViewModel(IMachine mach) 
{
        _mach = machCfg;
}

public interface IEquipmentDataFactory 
{
    IEquipmentData Create(IMachine mach);
    void Release(IMachine mach);
}
```

Here is my registration code:

```
container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
container.Register(
    Component.For<IWindsorContainer>().Instance(container),
    Component.For<IEquipmentData>().ImplementedBy<EquipmentData>(),
    Component.For<IMachine>().ImplementedBy<Machine>(),
    Component.For<IEquipmentDataFactory>().AsFactory());
```

When I call the Create method, it injects a newly instantiated object rather than the one I pass.  If I remove the `Component.For<IMachine>` entry in my registration, it then gives me a Missing Dependency.

```
IEquipmentData ed = null;
IMachine m = GetMachine();
ed = factory.Create(m);
```

How do I get Windsor to use the object I'm passing to the factory?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that using the `TypedFactoryFacility` Castle knows how to resolve for you the `IEquipmentData` (potentially) but when it tried to resolve it's dependencies it fails because they are not registered and there is no other `SubResolver` with the knowledge of how to resolve the `IMachine`.

Using the following classes: (Those in the question do not compile)

```
public class IMachine
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
}

public interface IEquipmentData { IMachine Machine { get; set; } }
public class MachineDataViewModel : IEquipmentData
{
    public IMachine Machine { get; set; }
    public MachineDataViewModel(IMachine machine) { Machine = machine; }
}
```

1. Option 1 - without the `TypedFactory`:

   ```
   WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
   container.Register(
       Component.For<IEquipmentData>()
                .ImplementedBy<MachineDataViewModel>()
                .LifestyleTransient());

   var machine = new IMachine();
   var resultWithoutFactory = container.Resolve<IEquipmentData>(new Dictionary<string, object> { ["machine"] = machine });
   ```
2. Option 2 - with the `TypedFactoryFacility`. In this case you will have to implement an `ITypedFactoryComponentSelector` to assist Castle and explain what the arguments for resolving the `IEquipmentData` is with the `IMachine` that you are passing.

   ```
   public interface IMachineFactory
   {
       IEquipmentData Create(IMachine machine);
   }

   public class EquipmentDataComponentSelector : ITypedFactoryComponentSelector
   {
       public Func<IKernelInternal, IReleasePolicy, object> SelectComponent(MethodInfo method, Type type, object[] arguments)
       {
           return (k, s) => k.Resolve<IEquipmentData>(new Dictionary<string, object> { ["machine"] = arguments[0] });
       }
   }
   ```

   Main:

   ```
   WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
   container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
   container.Register(
       Component.For<IEquipmentData>()
                .ImplementedBy<MachineDataViewModel>()
                .LifestyleTransient(),
       Component.For<EquipmentDataComponentSelector>(),
       Component.For<IMachineFactory>()
                .AsFactory(f => f.SelectedWith<EquipmentDataComponentSelector>()));

   var machine = new IMachine();
   var factory = container.Resolve<IMachineFactory>();
   var resultWithFactory = factory.Create(machine);
   ```

Result: (machine passed to container/factory is the one in the `IEquipmentData`)

[image]